# Re-entering Cloud Datalab from docker?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-datalab, google-earth-engine

I am using docker to get on a Cloud Datalab so I can use google earth engine.

I initially set things up by using these directions for windows, https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install-datalab-local.  Everything worked fine and I got into datalab.  Do I have to re-follow these exact instructions to reconnect every time or is there a faster way to re-establish the connection?

I tried to navigate to the workspace that was set up and ran `docker run -it -p "127.0.0.1:8081:8080" -v "%WORKSPACE%:/content" -e "PROJECT_ID=%GCP_PROJECT_ID%" %CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME%`

but that returned: `Run a Command in a new container`

Comment: Yep, that did work

Comment: Moving this text to answer then for better readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do this

```
docker run --name earthengine -d -p "127.0.0.1:8081:8080" -v "%WORKSPACE%:/content" -e "PROJECT_ID=%GCP_PROJECT_ID%" %CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME%.
```

This will run the container in background. Then whenever you want to get inside it use

```
docker exec -it earthengine bash
```

This may or may not worked depending on the startup commands. Also from the documentation it does look like the profile should be re-usable. Also I assume you re-define the environment variables again before running the command